# Is there a way to initialize for all my unit tests suite in Flutter/Dart executing a function?

Tags: unit-testing, dart, dart-test

The idea is to execute a common initialization for all unit tests in the suite, I mean, like executing a `setupAll()` before any test (that are written already) . Then I'd have an external component like `setupInitializers()` that is a global function or something that I could put on every unit test file easily and runs before each test.

```dart
   void main() {
      setupInitializers();
      ...
      ...
      // rest of the unit tests
   }
```

Is it clear the idea?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that `setUpAll` actually exists.

It requires a `dynamic Function` as a parameter, like the example below:

```
void main() {
    setUpAll(setupInitializers);

    test('your test here', () {
        // ...
    });
}

void setupInitializers() {
  // your initialization here
}
```

For more information you can go over the [official documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/setUpAll.html).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @alvaro This answer does not answer the question, because you are using the premises I'm asking.